# How do I move JUnit classes into a package?

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I'm working on a Java project, and currently have JUnit 4 set up to run some unit tests.

In this makefile: https://github.com/bprollinson/larp/blob/master/Makefile I'm using the "test" target to run tests. This works fine.

However, I want to change the directory structure of the unit tests from being flat (all in src/test) to mirror the application code directory structure. Application directory structure currently looks like:

src/main/larp/parser/contextfreelanguage
src/main/larp/parser/regularlanguage
src/main/larp/parsertree/regularlanguage
...

I've tried moving a test class into this directory structure, then adding the appropriate namespace declaration at the top of the file (e.g. moved src/tests/DFATest.java into src/test/larp/automaton and added "package larp.automaton;" at the top).

However, it generates the following error:
Could not find class [Classname]

Is there something special I need to do to get JUnit to tie into namespaces in unit test classes.

Comment: Regarding packages and visibility, there is no difference between test and tested code. Same rules. But please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Comment: check your project location and find your .class file and then edit and mention there directory structure instead of src/test

Comment: @GauravRai1512 Your comment was helpful. I was able to somewhat get it going by compiling the file in the subdirectory explicitly and then adding larp.automaton in the prefix of the class name when running.

I was just wondering if there is some better way to handle adding the prefixes without having to use the find command and having to manipulate path strings.

Comment: Sure. The trick was in understanding the basic requirements of simply compiling the test file then prefixing the class name with the namespace using dot separators when running the test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your project location and find your .class file and then edit and mention new directory structure instead of src/test.